# The Grinder - What is 'Insert Command' in TCPProxy Console

Tags: jython, grinder, jython-2.5

Grinder documentation saying lot of benefits of TCPProxy console. Like, record the response, auto generate the Jython test scripts and a lot. I am very happy for that. Sorry to say, but I am not able to find how to use it. Like, I see some thing 'Insert command and press enter' text box and 'insert command' button. But I did not find any details, what should I write in that text box. And how to use TCPProxy Console. 
But Grinder Documentation showing some generated scripts also. But how it generated, I did not find any details.

Please help me, if any body know.

Answer (score 0):

TCPProxy Console is very easy to use than I expected. It is some thing like Selenium Mozilla Firefox plugin.

One of friends from grinder-user gave a solution. I hope it will helpful to you also.

1. Start TCP Proxy (details in the above doc), default port is 8001.
2. Configure browser to use the localhost:8001 port so HTTP traffic generated by your browser goes through TCP Proxy
3. Run the steps in the browser for the testcase
4. Click STOP on the TCP Proxy dialog and the resulting grinder script will be generated